# How do I perform Gesture Recognition with CyberGlove II

Tags: visual-c++, gesture-recognition, cyberglove

I'm working on a project to try to `Recognize Gestures` with [CyberGlove II](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3MvE.jpg).

When I perform `GetDataGlove Demo` (present in the `SDK`) I get this results. ([See results in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNafo.png))

```
Glove:
0 0.38016 -0.13131 -0.12843
1 -0.09696 -0.20426 -0.0753
2 0.1725 0.01804 -012612
3 0.36897 -0.30396 0.01051
4 0.31597 -0.273 -0.2964
Tracker:
0 0 0
0 0 0 0

Glove:
0 0.38016 -0.13131 -0.12843
1 -0.09696 -0.20426 -0.0753
2 0.1725 0.01804 -012612
3 0.36897 -0.30396 0.01051
4 0.31597 -0.273 -0.2964
Tracker:
0 0 0
0 0 0 0

Glove:
0 0.38016 -0.13131 -0.12843
1 -0.09696 -0.20426 -0.0753
2 0.1725 0.01804 -012612
3 0.36897 -0.30396 0.01051
4 0.31597 -0.273 -0.2964
Tracker:
0 0 0
0 0 0 0

...
```

- If I do the same gesture the above values will be very similar but different.
- The values 0 to 4 represents each finger and the 3 values represent each joint of the finger.

But I have two questions:

1. How do you interpret those data in `Gesture Recognition`?
2. Which is the maximum and minimum value that each sensors returns?

PS.: The most important to me is learn how interpret the Sensors Data. With some didactic sample. I want to recognize the gestures from `Brazil Sign Languages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CyberGlove API` doesn't offer something native to this recognition. As the gesture data to a same gesture changes, I had to use Machine Learning. I used the [Microsoft Azure Machine Learning](https://studio.azureml.net/) and the service is based on `JSON`.

First I had to create a `.csv` with the gestures mapping that I would like to recognize. I did the mapping of gestures `100` times for each gesture. This amount that has been shown reasonable for recognition and the performance was also very interesting.